# HTML5 Microphone capture stops after 5 seconds in Firefox

Tags: audio, web-audio-api, getusermedia

I'm capturing audio input from microphone with getUserMedia() function, works fine in chrome, but in firefox sound dies out after 5 seconds. If I send request for microphone again (without reloading the page) same thing happens. Here is the code (I used http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Live-Web-Audio-Input-Enabled as guidance):

```
//getting the function depending on browser

navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia);

// success callback when requesting audio input stream
function gotAudioStream(stream) {
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    var audioContext = new AudioContext();

    // Create an AudioNode from the stream.
    var mediaStreamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource( stream );

    // Connect it to the destination to hear yourself (or any other node for processing!)
    mediaStreamSource.connect( audioContext.destination );
}


function gotError(err) {
      alert("An error occured! " + err);
}


//when button clicked, browser asks a permission to access microphone

jQuery("#sound_on").click(function()
{
    navigator.getMedia({audio: true},gotAudioStream,gotError);
});
```

Any ideas?

---

### EDIT/UPDATE

Thank you, csch, for the reference. Workaround by Karoun Kasraie worked!

```
context = new AudioContext();

navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true }, function(stream) {
  // the important thing is to save a reference to the MediaStreamAudioSourceNode
  // thus, *window*.source or any other object reference will do
  window.source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  source.connect(context.destination);
}, alert);
```

Comment: I am seeing the same problem here!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a bug in Firefox, it can be found here:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=934512

There's also a workaround:

```js
context = new AudioContext();

navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true }, function(stream) {
  // the important thing is to save a reference to the MediaStreamAudioSourceNode
  // thus, *window*.source or any other object reference will do
  window.source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  source.connect(context.destination);
}, alert);
```

[source](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=934512#c5)

Comment: Does this workaround still work for anyone in firefox 33? as soon as my callback finishes the mic stops recording.

Comment: @ThrowsException I just tested it and it works. It would be good to point out that the bug happens because the source is garbage collected.

Comment: Facing a similar issue and the above workaround doesn't really work for me as it looks like the problem is related to the Android build I have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230021/microphone-gets-disconnected-automatically-on-android-browser