# How can Web Audio API get the amount of a buffer already played and schedule the next buffer to play instantly after it continuously?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, timing

The hardcoded audio effects are an important tool, but sometimes what you want is to continuously redefine the sound at the sample level by potentially different and very nonlinear or even turing-complete function each sample, so the only way is to write numbers, in range -1 to 1, directly into a buffer.

Its often said that generating realtime sound samples in javascript has timing problems.

Since its for realtime sound that will depend on other game controls, like the frequency being proportional to mouse position or what camera sees, I need to know how much more buffer to precompute and schedule to play, each time javascript again runs, maybe on a timer of interval a few milliseconds or on some events (and which events could do that?).

I've done that in my http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsoundcard software for java, which keeps statistics on data remaining to be consumed in microphone buffer and data queued in speakers buffer and uses that to continuously adjust a ratio of consuming microphone frames to producing speaker frames, mostly between .99 and 1.01, in a linear interpolated way, so when one buffer gets a little too big it shrinks faster, and the delay between speakers and microphone, for any possible sound effect defined in a Java function, quickly shrinks. You get less delay because it watches the timing and adjusts buffer use by statistics.

I want to do that with Web Audio API, at the javascript level if possible, or if necessary I would consider porting some of the JSoundCard code to that project if their way of computing sound is compatible.

What should I do to get access to how much of a buffer has been used?

How can I schedule another buffer to play instantly continuing at the end of playing a buffer I started earlier?

I would need to know how much is left of playing the first buffer to choose how much more buffer to add, since little errors in timing build up to big delays.

Heres javascript code (that works in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera in Windows 7) to generate a one time sound (which continuously rises in frequency) starting at a specific time:

```
var audConType = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;  
var context = new audConType();
var around = 0;
var aroundSpeed = .1;
var soundFunc = function(amplitudeIn){ //ignore amplitudeIn for now
    aroundSpeed += .000002;
    return Math.sin(around += aroundSpeed);
};
var channels = 1;
var howManyFrames = 50000;
var rate = 44100;
var buffer = context.createBuffer(channels, howManyFrames, rate);
for(var channel=0; channel<channels; channel++){
    var chanBuf = buffer.getChannelData(channel);
    for (var f=0; f<howManyFrames; f++){
        chanBuf[f] = soundFunc(0);
    }
}
var source = context.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = buffer;
source.connect(context.destination);
source.start();
```

EDIT, new code after cwilso's response:

ScriptProcessorNode does allow me to process microphone samples with javascript code and send that to speakers in Firefox (why not Chrome and Opera too?), but theres a 1/3 second delay which makes it impractical for a live music performance or for events in games. Is there a way to set the microphone buffer size?

```
var volume = .7;
var maxMicrophoneAmplitude = 1;
var soundFunc = function(ins, outs){
    var microphoneAmplitude = ins[0];
    var estimatedFramesPerSecond = 44100;
    var decaySeconds = .1;
    var decay = 1/(estimatedFramesPerSecond*decaySeconds);
    maxMicrophoneAmplitude = Math.max(maxMicrophoneAmplitude, microphoneAmplitude)*(1-decay);
    microphoneAmplitude/maxMicrophoneAmplitude * volume
    outs[0] = microphoneAmplitude/maxMicrophoneAmplitude * volume;
};
soundFunc.inSize = 1;
soundFunc.outSize = 1;
var inputNodes = {};
window.onload = function(){
    var context = new AudioContext();
    if(!navigator.getUserMedia && navigator['mozGetUserMedia']){
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator['mozGetUserMedia'];
    }
    if(!navigator.getUserMedia && navigator['webkitGetUserMedia']){
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator['webkitGetUserMedia'];
    }
    if(!navigator.getUserMedia && navigator['msGetUserMedia']){
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator['msGetUserMedia'];
    }
    var framesPerBuffer = 1024;
    var scriptNode = context.createScriptProcessor(framesPerBuffer, 1, 1);
    scriptNode.onaudioprocess = function(audioProcessingEvent){
        var inputBuffer = audioProcessingEvent.inputBuffer;
        var outputBuffer = audioProcessingEvent.outputBuffer;
        var chansIn = [];
        var chansOut = [];
        for(var c=0; c<inputBuffer.numberOfChannels; c++){
            chansIn[c] = inputBuffer.getChannelData(c);
        }
        for(var c=0; c<outputBuffer.numberOfChannels; c++){
            chansOut[c] = outputBuffer.getChannelData(c);
        }
        var ins = new Float32Array(inputBuffer.numberOfChannels);
        var outs = new Float32Array(outputBuffer.numberOfChannels);
        for(var f=0; f<framesPerBuffer; f++){
            for(var c=0; c<inputBuffer.numberOfChannels; c++){
                ins[c] = chansIn[c][f];
            }
            soundFunc(ins, outs);
            for(var c=0; c<outputBuffer.numberOfChannels; c++){
                chansOut[c][f] = outs[c];
            }
        }

    }
    if(navigator.getUserMedia){
        navigator.getUserMedia(
            {'audio':true},
            function(stream){
                var input = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
                //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860468/html5-microphone-capture-stops-after-5-seconds-in-firefox says to save a reference to avoid sound ending after 5 seconds
                inputNodes.mic = input;
                input.connect(scriptNode);
                scriptNode.connect(context.destination);
                input.start();
            },
            function(e){ alert('Error capturing audio. e='+e); }
        );
    }else alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.'); 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is not to use AudioBuffers, but use a ScriptProcessor (currently; this will be replaced by AudioWorkers, but they're not yet implemented anywhere).  That will give you complete control over the audio bits in a dynamic way.

Comment: For me buffers work flawlessly when scheduled to start and stop after each other. They allow arbitrary amount of audio to be  buffered  without any latency (just the time to generate the buffer) whereas processor has a limit of 16k samples with horrible latency despite of such a small buffer size. Buffers can also be instantly stopped and restarted. And when UI is blocked for a long time (e.g. when the popup for do you want to close this page is active), processor will cause horrible noise. Buffers work so well I don't know I will even use the audioworker when it is finally implemented.

Comment: To quote from the original question: "sometimes what you want is to continuously redefine the sound at the sample level by potentially different and very nonlinear or even turing-complete function each sample, so the only way is to write numbers, in range -1 to 1, directly into a buffer."  That sounds EXACTLY like the target scenario for AudioWorkers.  (AudioWorker will fix the real-world problems of ScriptProcessor, like the UI blocking issues.)  If buffers work for you, use them; the proper scheduling of them is frequently problematic, which is why I wouldn't point to that solution first.