# How to set microphone buffer size in Web Audio API to avoid the 1/3 second delay (which is much faster in Java)?

Tags: buffer, delay, web-audio-api, microphone

This code works in Firefox in Windows 7. It plays transformed microphone on speakers. Its transformed by javascript code as numbers ranging -1 to 1 for audio amplitudes many times per second. It has a 1/3 second delay, but the same hardware runs much faster in java with my https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsoundcard software which adjusts buffer use by timing statistics. They both get faster when OS process thread priority is raised, but java is still much faster. Theres no reason Firefox or Web Audio API should have that much more delay, even though its become the norm that things dont work well in browsers, but with HTML5 (which is an open standard in progress) thats changing. Is there somewhere in Web Audio API to adjust the microphone buffer size?

```
var volume = .7;
var maxMicrophoneAmplitude = 1;
var soundFunc = function(ins, outs){
    var microphoneAmplitude = ins[0];
    var estimatedFramesPerSecond = 44100;
    var decaySeconds = .1;
    var decay = 1/(estimatedFramesPerSecond*decaySeconds);
    maxMicrophoneAmplitude = Math.max(maxMicrophoneAmplitude, microphoneAmplitude)*(1-decay);
    microphoneAmplitude/maxMicrophoneAmplitude * volume
    outs[0] = microphoneAmplitude/maxMicrophoneAmplitude * volume;
};
soundFunc.inSize = 1;
soundFunc.outSize = 1;
var inputNodes = {};
window.onload = function(){
    var context = new AudioContext();
    if(!navigator.getUserMedia && navigator['mozGetUserMedia']){
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator['mozGetUserMedia'];
    }
    if(!navigator.getUserMedia && navigator['webkitGetUserMedia']){
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator['webkitGetUserMedia'];
    }
    if(!navigator.getUserMedia && navigator['msGetUserMedia']){
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator['msGetUserMedia'];
    }
    var framesPerBuffer = 1024;
    var scriptNode = context.createScriptProcessor(framesPerBuffer, 1, 1);
    scriptNode.onaudioprocess = function(audioProcessingEvent){
        var inputBuffer = audioProcessingEvent.inputBuffer;
        var outputBuffer = audioProcessingEvent.outputBuffer;
        var chansIn = [];
        var chansOut = [];
        for(var c=0; c<inputBuffer.numberOfChannels; c++){
            chansIn[c] = inputBuffer.getChannelData(c);
        }
        for(var c=0; c<outputBuffer.numberOfChannels; c++){
            chansOut[c] = outputBuffer.getChannelData(c);
        }
        var ins = new Float32Array(inputBuffer.numberOfChannels);
        var outs = new Float32Array(outputBuffer.numberOfChannels);
        for(var f=0; f<framesPerBuffer; f++){
            for(var c=0; c<inputBuffer.numberOfChannels; c++){
                ins[c] = chansIn[c][f];
            }
            soundFunc(ins, outs);
            for(var c=0; c<outputBuffer.numberOfChannels; c++){
                chansOut[c][f] = outs[c];
            }
        }       
    }
    if(navigator.getUserMedia){
        navigator.getUserMedia(
            {'audio':true},
            function(stream){
                var input = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
                //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860468/html5-microphone-capture-stops-after-5-seconds-in-firefox says to save a reference to avoid sound ending after 5 seconds
                inputNodes.mic = input;
                input.connect(scriptNode);
                scriptNode.connect(context.destination);
                input.start();
            },
            function(e){ alert('Error capturing audio. e='+e); }
        );
    }else alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.'); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I do believe (@cwilso can probably correct me on this if I'm wrong) that the API uses a model where samples are pulled from the nodes, rather than the nodes pushing the samples to the nodes following it. That means that the buffer size that you set in your script processor is the source of the delay, not the input buffer size of the microphone stream. Try setting that buffer size lower.

```
var framesPerBuffer = 256;
var scriptNode = context.createScriptProcessor(framesPerBuffer, 1, 1);
```

Comment: 1/3 of a second (300ms) seems awfully high.  Yes, the buffer size of the scriptprocessor is a large cost - the smaller the better, although it requires a faster CPU then (i.e., it's a tradeoff - not every system can support a buffer of 256 without glitching).  AudioWorkers will help this; until then, you really want to do as much processing as possible using native Web Audio nodes, not ScriptProcessor.  (the hop across from the Web Audio thread to the main thread is painfully slow.)  I'm guessing the input buffer is very large on your device for some reason.  How is it in Chrome?